# Primefaces: splitButton's menu appended to the body

Tags: css, jsf, button, primefaces, split

**My Code:**

```
<p:splitButton value="View">
    <p:menuitem value="Edit" icon="ui-icon-edit" />
    <p:menuitem value="Delete" icon="ui-icon-delete"/>
</p:splitButton>
```

that code is rendering the menu appended to the body, for example:

```
<body>
    <form>
        <table>
            <tr>
                <button id="splitbutton".../>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </form>
    <div id="menu-for-splitbutton">
        <a id="menu1"... >Edit</a>
        <a id="menu2"... >Delete</a>
    </div>
</body>
```

I need the menu relative to the splitbutton or adjacent, for example:

```
<body>
    <form>
        <table>
            <tr>
                <button id="splitbutton".../>
                <div id="menu-for-splitbutton">
                    <a id="menu1"... >Edit</a>
                    <a id="menu2"... >Delete</a>
                </div>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </form>
</body>
```

I'm using :hover (CSS) to show the split button when the cursor is over a row, but is not hiding the context menu when any row is unselected because the menu is not inside the TR tag... How I can resolve this?